# How to add a library to eclipse of .jar files that are NOT a "User Library"?

Tags: eclipse, jar, java

I am attempting to add a group of .jar files to my build path for a project that is under source control. Specifically I have downloaded the Smack API and I have a folder located in my project/libs/ that contains the multiple smack .jar files I will need.

If I go to Project > Properties... and try to use "Add Library..." under the "Libraries" tab. The only option that makes sense is to add an "User Library". However, this doesn't work with source control as User Libraries appear to be defined in the workspace/.metadata/ folder, and is not under source control.

I can add each .jar file using Project > Properties... using "Add JARs..." under the "Libraries" tab, but then each .jar shows up separately in the build path (not grouped neatly together like other system libraries). Between HAPI, HTTP Components, and Smack .jar's I need, the build path contains a lot of separate jar files and I just want to group them together.

Is this a limitation of Eclipse? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know if I understood well, but I think it's normal behaviour. Each jar added to your project is a separate entry, and it isn't grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

[image]  Here's the link from one of my Eclipse projects.  Eclipse does not group them together - you just add each jar and get the list from this screen.  To add libs that are in the project folder structure, use Add Jars..., for external jars, use Add External Jars...

Comment: Thanks, that's what mine looks like too. I just thought if I could add them as a library it would look cleaner.

Comment: Agreed but I have not seen Eclipse do that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @mikemil, add external jar is the way for non-web apps.

If your project is a web application and has a .../WEB-INF directory, you can put the jar in the .../WEB-INF/lib directory and it will be in the deployed WAR file as well as in the build path.

Comment: It is a non-web app, but adding external jar's use an absolute path which breaks each developer's build environment unless they place the jar's in the same place. So we add the jar's to our projects lib/ folder so that we can use "Add Jar" instead and use relative paths.

It would just be nice to use a library to "clean" up the build path and have the jar files logically separated.

Comment: We use myEclipse, which includes some level of maven support.  This in turn allows me to inlude jars from the maven repository as follows: M2_REPO/path/to/jar/jar_file.jar  The M2_REPO expands to the local maven repository directory.